# Expo publish - using a cached project alert

Tags: expo

I wanted to make my app accessible without local connection via `expo publish`. After running the command i successfully get a link to the project page. But if i try to open the app via the project page in Expo Go, it displays this alert:

[image]

The project is loaded on my device(i suppose it is because it is cached in my device), but it is not opening for anyone else. How to load it with network instead of cache? My network is connected even though the alert tells to check it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was my mistake, had to go through the expo documentations to find a [guide](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/sharing-preview-releases/) that simply states:

> Invite your teammate to the Expo account that owns the project.

I thought since the project privacy is set to public, this was not mandatory. It is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem today - for me the issue was being on a public WiFi network (at a co-working space) that I think must have some kind of network filtering that presumably blocked fetching new Expo packages.

Switching WiFi off on my phone and using cellular resolved the issue.

Comment: I’m also having this same issue, however, switching to a cellular network did not resolve my issue. I believe @AidasV is right in the sense we need to invite collaborators to avoid seeing the message. I’m still looking for a work around within the project to avoid seeing it